# How many ways letters be placed so at least two of them are in wrong envelopes?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A person writes letters to six friends and their addresses to corresponding envelopes.  In how many ways can the letters be placed in the envelopes so that **at least two of them are in wrong envelopes**?

Comment: Note: you can _never_ have only $1$ letter in the wrong envelope.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan - you can if one envelope is empty and another contains two letters, though this question probably assumes each envelope contains exactly one letter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the person is placing the letters in the envelopes at random, and the order matters, there will be $6! = 720$ ways of placing the letters, and only of those has all of the letters placed correctly. So there are $719$ ways of making a mistake. (Note that one mistake means at least 2 are incorrect)